# How can I view my activity attachments inline (i.e. on the webpage)?

Tags: images, attachments

When I view an activity, I can see there are several attached images.  Is there a way to have the images show up on the activity "view" page?

I know how to write an extension to do this; I'm looking for answers that show extensions that are already written, or configurations I hadn't considered.

This is on WordPress, to preclude the "use Views" answers :)

Comment: ha. beat me to that non-suggestion then.

Comment: I almost called you out by name @petednz-fuzion :)

Comment: happened at school a lot too